# if condition in laravel query

Tags: laravel, if-statement

some time some variables are null so how check the variable is not null and apply direct in query

```
 $fiter_products = DB::table('products')->DISTINCT('modalid')->DISTINCT('brandid')->select('rimdiameter','modalid','modalname1','modalname2','image1','brand','minprice','maxprice')->where('hubbore','>=',$centre_bore)->where('boltpattern',$boltptn)->where('rimdiameter', $diameter)->where('rimwidth', $width)->where('rimwidthfront', $frontwid)->where('construction', $construct)->where('modalname2', $color)->where('brand', $brand)->get();
```

any way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass another Closure as the third parameter to the [when](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses)  method. This Closure will execute if the first parameter evaluates as false.

```php
$fiter_products = DB::table('products')
                   ->DISTINCT('modalid')
                   ->DISTINCT('brandid')
                   ->select('rimdiameter','modalid','modalname1','modalname2','image1','brand','minprice','maxprice')
->when($centre_bore, function($query,  $centre_bore) {
    $query->where('hubbore','>=',$centre_bore);
})->when($boltptn, function($query, $boltptn) {
    $query->where('boltpattern',$boltptn);
})...
```

Comment: what is $query param

Comment: @andrewghosh `$query` is query-builder

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whereNotNull('field)` method. [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries):

> The whereNotNull method verifies that the column's value is not NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = DB::table('products')->DISTINCT('modalid')->DISTINCT('brandid')->select('rimdiameter','modalid','modalname1','modalname2','image1','brand','minprice','maxprice');

if(isset($centre_bore)){
    $product->where('hubbore','>=',$centre_bore);
}

if(isset($boltptn)){
    $product->where('boltpattern',$boltptn);
}

if(isset($diameter)){
    $product->where('rimdiameter', $diameter);
}

if(isset($width)){
    $product->where('rimwidth', $width);
}

if(isset($frontwid)){
    $product->where('rimwidthfront', $frontwid);
}

if(isset($construct)){
    $product->where('construction', $construct);
}

if(isset($color)){
    $product->where('modalname2', $color);
}

if(isset($brand)){
    $product->where('brand', $brand);
}     

$fiter_products = $product->get();
```